# TypeScript importing module path

Tags: typescript

I have the following file:

`myProjectRoot/src/server.ts`

Inside this it has:

`import testRouter from 'module/lib';`

I have a library which exports a default value at:

`myProjectRoot/src/module/lib.ts`

My `myProjectRoot/tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src/"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I get the error: `[ERROR] 15:50:42 Error: Cannot find module 'module/lib'`

Comment: I think you can just put `src/` if the tsconfig is on the root already

Comment: @MikeTung I would prefer not to do so.

Comment: @MikeTung Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://decembersoft.com/posts/say-goodbye-to-relative-paths-in-typescript-imports/) could help.

Comment: @Paleo I was looking for this. I have seen it work using `paths`

Comment: I don't see what your error has to do with the other information you showed.  You are importing `testRouter` from `module/lib` but it is complaining about an import to `module/test`.  The import you showed should work just fine given the `baseUrl` and, given that the error isn't talking about that import, it seems it is working just fine.

Comment: Also, what are you using `baseUrl` for?  What is your module loader at runtime?  Are you moving your source files into a common folder as a build step?  If you're just running this through node then you probably want `paths` as others have mentioned and not `baseUrl`.  Or to put it more generally, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Paleo Is this the only way? So much wasteful boilerplate code... Not very effective. :/

Comment: I personally prefer not to use this feature and let the IDE generate relative paths in imports. Maybe it's possible to configure the IDE in order to hide imports if they are too ugly for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here.

## Use Relative Imports

This is the simplest option. Just specify relative paths when importing stuff.

```
import testRouter from './module/lib';
```

## Set Up Import Aliases

You can edit your `tsconfig.json` so that it resolves the path you typed.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src/",
        "paths": {
            "./*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see, TypeScript will now resolve the import properly.

[image: Image of VS Code resolving the import correctly.]

**BEWARE:** The above just tells the TypeScript compiler that paths *can* be resolved from `src`, but *does not affect code emit*. For example, the `import` statement still gets compiled to the following:

```
const lib_1 = require("module/lib");
```

This means that unless you have another build tool which can transform that `require` into a relative path, *the import will not work at runtime* even though TypeScript says it's okay.

[image: Image of Node throwing due to bad module resolution.]